# Can I put array.foreach inside Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

our Typescript function is like this:

```
export async function filterStatus(extractionId: string, inputIds: Set<string>, allStatus: StatusType[]): Promise<string[]> {
  const result: string[] = [];
  await Promise.all(allStatus.map(async (status) => {
    const subextStatus = await queryDynamoDB(status, ["id"]);
    // queryDynamoDB() returns Promise<AWS.DynamoDB.AttributeMap[]> Everything inside it uses await for nonblocking calls.
    subextStatus.forEach(v => {
      const dynamoData = AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall(v);
      if (!dynamoData || !("id" in dynamoData)) {
        throw new Error(`Unable to unmarshall dynamo items to "id": ${util.inspect(dynamoData)}`);
      }
      if (inputIds.has(v["id"])) {
        result.push(v["id"]);
      }
    });
  }));
  return result;
}
```

Basically, given inputIds, I want to filter them that satisfy some condition based on allStatus.

From other posts, it seems inside forEach we'd better not run await/async functions. But here subextStatus is already Resolved. So, it should be just AWS.DynamoDB.AttributeMap[]. Then Array.forEach is also blocking. Am I right?

The exact problem I face is that sometimes inputIds become undefined (so inputIds.has() will fail) although the caller already checked it has value. Is it possible that filterStatus function returns but forEach is still working.

Update about the caller of filterStatus function. The caller is basically a Map<string, Set> and the problem here is that sometimes Set becomes undefined.

```
export async function getRecentSubext(): Promise<Map<string, Set<string>>> {
    const results = new Map<string, Set<string>>();
    for (const extractor in ExtractorType) {
        const oneQueryResult = await someDynamoDBCall(extractor);
        const queryResults: AWS.DynamoDB.AttributeMap[] = oneQueryResult.Items;
        const dynamoData = AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall(v);
        if (!dynamoData || !(["id", "extraction_id"].every(element => element in dynamoData))) {
          throw new Error(`Unable to unmarshall dynamo items to "id", "extraction_id": ${util.inspect(dynamoData)}`);
        }

        if (!results.has(dynamoData["extraction_id"])) {
          results.set(dynamoData["extraction_id"], new Set<string>());
        }
       results.get(dynamoData["extraction_id"])!.add(dynamoData["id"]);
    } 
    return results;
}


export async function handler(): Promise<void> {
   // omitting many lines
   const candidateSubexts: Map<string, Set<string>> = await getRecentSubext();  // checked closely, everything inside is blocking by using await. 
   for (const extraction of extractions) {
      const subExtractionCount: CountData = await countSubexts(); // This function actually has some problem, we did not await sometimes inside.

      if (candidateSubexts.has(extraction.id)) {
         await filterStatus(extraction.id, candidateSubexts.get(extraction.id), allStatus);
      }
   }
   // Other logic 
}
```

The countSubexts() function is the only place we found some issue. Inside it sometimes we just return asyncFunc, instead of return await asyncFunc. But the return value of countSubexts() function is not used in filterStatus().

Thanks.

Comment: In what respect are `has` and `push` "blocking" functions?

Comment: From what is posted, it’s impossible for `inputIds` to turn from a set of string into `undefined` during fn execution. Any chance you pass invalid args to `filterStatus` when you call it?

Comment: has() and push() are not async function. They are blocking, right?

We do see the caller has some issue, but was long before this code.

Comment: I updated the question with more details on the caller. Thank you.

Comment: "*it seems inside forEach we'd better not run await/async functions*" - yes, but that's not what you are doing, right? The only functions you call inside the `forEach` callback are `unmarshall`, `inspect`, `has` and `push`, and they're all synchronous.

Comment: Right, everything inside forEach are unmarshall, inspect, has and push. That is why I am confused how it could become undefined. I pasted the caller functions but still dont really understand.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is single threaded. The only thing you won't have control over is the insertion order.

If that is important to you, you can just refactor it this way:

```
export async function filterStatus(extractionId: string, inputIds: Set<string>, allStatus: StatusType[]): Promise<string[]> {
  const result: string[] = [];
  const queryResults = await Promise.all(allStatus.map((status) => queryDynamoDB(status, ["id"]));

  queryResults.forEach(subextStatus => {
    subextStatus.forEach(v => {
      const dynamoData = AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall(v);
      if (!dynamoData || !("id" in dynamoData)) {
        throw new Error(`Unable to unmarshall dynamo items to "id": ${util.inspect(dynamoData)}`);
      }
      if (inputIds.has(v["id"])) {
        result.push(v["id"]);
      }
    });
  });

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. We don't care about insertion order. But your code is definitely simpler, easier to understand. Still I dont understand why inputIds could become undefined. I am afraid we have some bug elsewhere.

Comment: `inputIds` is a Set, so an object, thus it's "passed by reference". Its content can be mutated elsewhere, but it cannot become `undefined` on its own inside the function.